# Nan Loss - Embedding layer with LSTM - 4D data

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to predict the value of one feature for 39 unique IDs. I am trying to solve this by using an Embedding layer before LSTM layer, and because I want to predict value of a feature for all unique IDs using a single model, but I'm getting 'nan' loss value. As of now, I have 360 sequences with 3 timesteps, 39 unique IDs and 8 features, and trying to predict one feature's value at 4th timestep (lead_time = 1). I understand that LSTM takes 3D data, therefore I also change the data shape in the model from `(num_seq,timesteps,IDs,features)` to `(num_seq,timesteps,IDs*features)`. I know that one of the reasons could be missing values in data, but I don't ahve any missing values in my data.I would appreciate any suggestions.
Shape of the data are as given below:

```
X_train_sequences = (360,3,39,8)
Y_train_sequences = (360,1,39,1)
X_train_arpt = (360,3,39,1)
```

I also squeezed the dimensions of Y_train_sequences and X_train_arpt to get the following shapes which are then given as an input to the model:

```
Y_sq = (360,39)
id_sq = (360,3,39)
```

The model architecture is as follows:

```
emb_size = 2

# Input layers
feature_inp = Input(shape = (num_timesteps,n_arpts,X_train_sequences.shape[-1],)) # (None,3,39,8)
print("feature_inp shape:",feature_inp.shape)

arpt_inp = Input(shape = (num_timesteps, n_arpts,)) # (None,3,39)
print("arpt_inp shape:",arpt_inp.shape)

# Embedding layer
arpt_emb = Embedding(n_arpts, emb_size, input_length=X_train_sequences.shape[3])(arpt_inp) # (None,3,39,2)
print("arpt_inp shape:",arpt_emb.shape)

# Concatenate features and embedding layer
concat = Concatenate(axis = -1)([feature_inp,arpt_emb]) # (None,3,39,10)
print("concat shape:",concat.shape)

# Reshape concat to 3-D tensor
concat_reshaped = Reshape((num_timesteps,-1))(concat) # (None,3,390)
print("concat_reshaped shape:",concat_reshaped.shape)

# LSTM layers
lstm_1 = LSTM(32,return_sequences=True)(concat_reshaped) # (None,3,32)
print("lstm_1 shape:",lstm_1.shape)

lstm_2 = LSTM(32,return_sequences=False)(lstm_1) # (None,32)
print("lstm_2 shape:",lstm_2.shape)

# Output 39 values corresponding to each ID
out = Dense(39, activation = 'tanh')(lstm_2) # (None,39)
print("out shape:",out.shape)

model = Model(inputs = [feature_inp,arpt_inp], outputs = out)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss= 'mse')
model.summary()
```

Output of model summary:

```
feature_inp shape: (None, 3, 39, 8)
arpt_inp shape: (None, 3, 39)
arpt_inp shape: (None, 3, 39, 2)
concat shape: (None, 3, 39, 10)
concat_reshaped shape: (None, 3, 390)
lstm_1 shape: (None, 3, 32)
lstm_2 shape: (None, 32)
out shape: (None, 39)
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_24 (InputLayer)          [(None, 3, 39)]      0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_23 (InputLayer)          [(None, 3, 39, 8)]   0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_10 (Embedding)       (None, 3, 39, 2)     78          ['input_24[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_7 (Concatenate)    (None, 3, 39, 10)    0           ['input_23[0][0]',               
                                                                  'embedding_10[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 reshape_6 (Reshape)            (None, 3, 390)       0           ['concatenate_7[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 lstm_9 (LSTM)                  (None, 3, 32)        54144       ['reshape_6[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 lstm_10 (LSTM)                 (None, 32)           8320        ['lstm_9[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)                (None, 39)           1287        ['lstm_10[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 63,829
Trainable params: 63,829
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Model fit:

```
model.fit([X_train_sequences,id_sq],Y_sq, epochs = 10)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
Epoch 1/10
12/12 [==============================] - 4s 10ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 5/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 6/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 7/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 8/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 9/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 10/10
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: nan
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f29143cdd50>
```

I am not understanding why I'm getting 'nan' loss.